# Change opacity of other tab when I hover current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I create a dropdown menu. I need when I hover to a tab, the opacity of other tabs in menu are change except the current tab I hover.

Example: when I hover to Home Tab, state of Home tab and list item is not changed (yellow color, opacity=1) but other tabs (Tutorial, Article, Inspiration) are changed (grey color, opacity=0.5)

```
<code>http://jsfiddle.net/dennisho/6fX42/2/</code>
```

Comment: please include the relevant code here as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sibling selector that will select all siblings to help select the other menu elements but you can use the `:not` selector

```
nav > ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fX42/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/6fX42/13/).

```
nav ul li {
    background-color: yellow;   
}

nav ul li:first-of-type { 
    border-top-left-radius:25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
}

nav ul li:last-of-type { 
    border-top-right-radius:25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
}

nav > ul li:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
nav > ul li:not(:hover){
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

But please include relevant code in your question so it is helpful for other people, too.

Comment: I saw your sample but I want opacity, color of both current tab and its list item is not change. It means color of current is yellow and the opacity of list item is NOT changed when hover.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer above to reflect that. Here's a [direct link to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/6fX42/13/)